# Los datos se revuelven al graficar

Tags: ggplot2

tengo un data.frame con familia, especie, lugar, sección y cantidad. Quiero hacer un gráfico de barras que muestre la "cantidad" de individuos de cada familia según lugar y sección. El gráfico en sí ya lo tengo, mi problema es que al graficar  salen datos revueltos y no los que deberían ser según la información original. De modo que, si tengo 2 o más especies de la misma familia no se suman entre sí o se suman con datos de otras familias. Este es mi código

```
ggplot(datos, aes(Familia, Cantidad), fill = Seccion))+
theme_bw()+
geom_col()+
facet_wrap(~Lugar, scales = "free")
```

Tengo otras cosas más pero son para la estética de los datos, como nombres de los ejes y así.

```
structure(list(Lugar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
c("playa", 
"rampa"), class = "factor"), Seccion = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("exterior", "interior"), class = "factor"), 
Familia = c("Sphaeromatidae", "Panopeidae", "Sphaeromatidae", 
"Petricolidae", "Talitridae", "Sphaeromatidae"), Especie = 
c("Sphaeroma_peruvianum", 
"Acantholobulus_mirafloresensis", "Sphaeroma_peruvianum", 
"Petricola_exarata", "Talitridae_sp1", "Sphaeroma_peruvianum"
), Cantidad = c(7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Bienvenido Randall a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega una muestra pequeña de los datos, por ejemplo, pegando la salida de `dput(head(datos))` a tu pregunta, sino es muy difícil poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en la creación del objeto `datos` en tu llamada a `structure()`. Al crear los `factor` "Lugar" y "Seccion" que contienen dos niveles, el vector que utilizas sólo contiene el valor `1L` repetido seis veces, debido a ello el segundo valor no llega a ser utilizado. Cuando usas el código de `ggplot2` el `facet_wrap()` sólo va a detectar un nivel en ambos casos.

El código de abajo utiliza `sample()` para que obtengas ambos niveles (Cambié un poco el formato para que sea más claro).

```r
datos <-
  structure(
    list(
      Lugar = structure(
        sample(1:2, 6, replace = TRUE),
        .Label = c("playa", "rampa"),
        class = "factor"),
      Seccion = structure(
        sample(1:2, 6, replace = TRUE),
        .Label = c("exterior", "interior"),
        class = "factor"),
      Familia = c("Sphaeromatidae",
        "Panopeidae",
        "Sphaeromatidae",
        "Petricolidae",
        "Talitridae",
        "Sphaeromatidae"),
      Especie = c("Sphaeroma_peruvianum",
          "Acantholobulus_mirafloresensis",
          "Sphaeroma_peruvianum",
          "Petricola_exarata",
          "Talitridae_sp1",
          "Sphaeroma_peruvianum"),
      Cantidad = c(7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )
```

Esto es lo que obtengo al usar tu código de ggplot2 (agregué la llamada a `library()`). El tuyo puede variar un poco debido a que `sample()` es aleatorio.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(datos, aes(Familia, Cantidad), fill = Seccion)+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~Lugar, scales = "free")
```

[image: ggplot2_facets]